# Loop through all elements in each container

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I need to loop through all items in each container, starting from 1 every time the loops reaches a new container.

Edit: added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ntv4k4LL/

E.g.

```
Container

 - 1 
 - 2
 - 3

Container

 - 1 
 - 2
 - 3
```

But at the moment it's going

```
Container

 - 1 
 - 2
 - 3

Container

 - 4 
 - 5
 - 6
```

Here is my code:

```
$('.index-slide-rel').each(function(){

     $(this).children('article').each(function(i,e){

         col++;

         if(i > 0 && i%cols === cols-1) {
             sx= 0;
             row++;
             col=1;
             sy += previewElementHeight;
         }                  
     })                     
});
```

Comment: Keep track of what the `$(this).closest(.index-slide-rel)` is and when that changes, reset `col = 0;`.

Comment: Here @scrowler http://jsfiddle.net/ntv4k4LL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.index-slide-rel').each(function(i, container) {
    // here, i should take the value 0 to 1, considering you have 2 containers.
    $(container).children('article').each(function(j, element) {
        // here, j should take the value 0 to 2, considering you have 3 elements.
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, The number of containers will be unknown. Is there a way to account for the unknown? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does not matter, the code above will work for any number of containers/elements (Considering the number fits in a 32 bit integer).